# Chamisha Asar Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred fifteen?

### ?חמישה עשר ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 315.

Is there a lazy gematria answer to this one? Perhaps, but it's still not ideal.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred fourteen entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Tzemach Tzadik](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9179&st=&pgnum=60&hilite=) the phoenix bird lives for 315 years. See also [Peniel](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41893&st=&pgnum=38&hilite=). Peniel says that when Adam and Chava ate from the Eitz HaDaas they also shared with all the animals and birds. The only one that refused the food from the Eitz HaDaas was the phoenix. In reward for that it lives a long life and regenerates after 315 years.

Comment: Like this [Phoenix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_(mythology))? That's a Jewish thing?

Comment: @DoubleAA R' Slifkin's [*Sacred Monsters*](http://zootorah.com/books/sacred-monsters) has a chapter on it.

Comment: @IsaacMoses: I guess my answer will be banned.

Comment: @GershonGold Only if you'll let us also ban the Tzemach Tzadik.